# Border vs. padding in CSS

Tags: css, border, padding

I'm attempting to understand the exact relation between padding and border in CSS.

Would it be accurate to say that a solid border of transparent color is essentially the same thing as the same amount of padding, and can be expected to behave similarly- except insofar as they will coexist on the same element rather than overwriting each other?

In other words, is there any case in which:

```
#Square1{
    padding: 50px;
}
```

, if replaced with:

```
#Square1{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

would be expected to display different behavior in any meaningful way, *except* if there was something like this in the same CSS file:

```
.ClassThatSquare1HappensToHave{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

, in which case you will effectively end up with twice the amount of border/padding/element-expanding space?

Comment: What if you need to use another border-style to #Square1?

Comment: Yep, I do appreciate that border-style can be used to create visual effects in a way that's not possible with padding. But, for instance, how it interacts with mouseovers and links will be the same no matter what the border-style is: with a 50px padding or 50px of border, moving the mouse to 35px to the left of the visible element will show title text, and clicking there will make a link work- in a way not true, for instance, with margin or outline. I'm trying to work out if, like margin and outline, there is a nonvisual difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. Note how overflow behaves differently both in the content that is left displayed (which is clipped to the padding edge) and the position of the scrollbar, which sits outside padding, but inside border.

```css
#Square1{
    padding: 50px;
}

#Square2{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 50px;
    border-color: transparent;
}

body {
  width:400px;
}

div {
  background-color:lightblue;
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="Square1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="Square2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
```

Comment: this is actually *the* answer. If you don't mind I would also add the fact that background will also behave differently due to background-origin being padding-box by default: https://jsfiddle.net/6zmc5hf4/ (let's have all the difference in one answer)

Comment: Sonuvabitch! Just when I thought I had a nice, simple answer, in you come with the complicated truth. Thanks both to you and @TemaniAfif.

Comment: @ooogooman yet another fundamental difference related to position:absolute: https://jsfiddle.net/4fb1pxac/1/ ... The reference is the padding-box and not the border-box

Answer (score 2):

They both belong to CSS box model but they serve different purposes.

In the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) :

> [image: SS]
>
> The **padding** area, bounded by the padding edge, extends the content area to include the element's padding. Its dimensions are the *padding-box width* and the *padding-box height*.
>   (...)
>
> The **border** area, bounded by the border edge, extends the padding area
>   to include the element's borders. Its dimensions are the *border-box*
>   *width* and the *border-box height*(...)
>
> If the `box-sizing` property is set to `border-box`, the border area's
>   size can be explicitly defined with the `width`, `min-width`, `max-width`,
>   `height`, `min-height`, and `max-height` properties.

---

With that said, you should use `padding` whenever you want to give inner space and use `border` to give exactly what it states - a border - a line that if has `padding` will show after the `padding` area.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question, css properties are always being used in quirky ways to create things that are normally not possible, So an answer that is *use it for what it's meant* is not an explanation and definitely doesn't answer the op's question *would be expected to display different behavior in any meaningful way*

Comment: The padding area's size can *also* be explicitly defined with the padding-bottom, padding-left, padding-right, and padding-top properties. Yes, border exists between padding and margin rather than between content and border. But are they different in any *other* fashion, when both are transparent?

Comment: @ooogooman  `Yes, border exists between padding and margin rather than between content and border.` how come border would exist between content and itself? `But are they different in any other fashion? `  I guess I've explain that in my answer.  a `padding` is to create a inner spacing while a `border` is to create exactly that a border, a line, which can be transparent giving the illusion of being a `padding`, but isn't. They are different. if you set them both, you see `border`adding space out of the padding area.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I've explain with the differences  between the properties and  when  those properties should be used properly. Creating in quirky ways (in this case) it is not the point. OP is trying to understand the differences between those properties.

Comment: @dippas: So, then: border is different from padding in that it can be given border-styles and border-colors to make it visible, and in that it lies in the next layer out in the box model. But it is *not* different in any other fashion, and the specific case of a transparent border on a paddingless element is identical for practical purposes to that of the same amount of padding on a borderless element?

Comment: Yes, but if the purpose is to create space why then use border transparent instead of padding?

Comment: @dippas I'm not asking whether this is something I *should* do, just trying to make sure I don't run afoul of some not-immediately-apparent nonvisual difference in page behavior like the difference between padding and *margin*- which highlights differently, displays mouseover text differently, acts differently on links, etc. You've cleared this up for me- thanks for your patience!